# Show progress in for loop by counting the images already processed [Python]

Tags: python, for-loop, enumeration

I would like to count the amount of pictures already converted. Therefore I have to modify `print('converting')` somehow.

```
def convert(self):          
        directory = [fn for fn in os.listdir(self.destination_folder) 
                      if any(fn.endswith(ext) for ext in included_extensions)]
        for item in directory:
            if item.endswith('.jpg' ): 
                img = Image.open(self.destination_folder + item)
                pathx = self.destination_folder + item
                convert='mogrify -virtual-pixel Black +distort Plane2Cylinder 53 -crop 2060x2060+620+202 %s' %pathx
                
                subprocess.run(convert, env={'PATH': path_cur})
                print('converting')
```

The output should be something like. `xxx` should be the total amount of files in `directory`.

```
converting [1/xxx]
converting [2/xxx]
converting [3/xxx]
...
```

How can I get this output?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: `for count, item in enumerate(directory, 1):` gives you the position number for each item you're looping over.

Comment: for this kind of thing that take time, I prefer to use a progress bar, like the [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having access to your data, something perhaps like:

```
def convert(self):          
        directory = [fn for fn in os.listdir(self.destination_folder) 
                      if any(fn.endswith(ext) for ext in included_extensions)]

        train_length = len(directory)
        counter = 1

        for item in directory:
            if item.endswith('.jpg' ): 
                img = Image.open(self.destination_folder + item)
                pathx = self.destination_folder + item
                convert='mogrify -virtual-pixel Black +distort Plane2Cylinder 53 -crop 2060x2060+620+202 %s' %pathx
                
                subprocess.run(convert, env={'PATH': path_cur})
                print('converting', '[',counter,'/', train_length, ']')
                counter += 1
```

The enumerate method in the comments above is better.